# Facebook opengraph problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a very strange problem with facebook OG. https://fit.upjet.com/en/pages/news/270/ - this is a link to one of the news of my site's news section. When i paste a direct link into "update status" window on my facebook page - i get the correct text an image from OG tags, debuger shows no problem and also shows info from OG. But when someone clicks like/send button he gets random picture and text from the site's slider. What's even stranger - i have this problem ONLY with news section, all other pages work perfectly fine. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in Facebook linter for URL you're using in the Like button http://goo.gl/o1mgL
Description in Russian is not a problem for Facebook, but most probably not exactly what you expected to see.

Please, spot the difference in url in your question and in the Like button on your page.

Solution - add language to the Like url.